# problem reading time stamp data from api in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

While reading data from http using rest api as source In copy data’s import schema functionality in Azure Data Factory I am unable to read proper format data in time stamp values. Can anyone please let me know how do u fix this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is the tag as read from ADF and actual tag from URL.

ADF Read:
"modified": 1452859829000,

Actual URL data:
 2016-01-15T05:10:29-07:00

Answer (score -3):

If you can share some data as to what is that you are seeing and what is expected , that will be great . My hunch is that the API you are referring is not a public facing and so helping without more data is really tough .

Comment: Here is the tag as read from ADF and actual tag from URL.

ADF Read: "modified": 1452859829000,

Actual URL data: 2016-01-15T05:10:29-07:00